# Is there a cleaner code for the PHPmailer in wordpress..?

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress

As a extended version to this question : [PHPMailer(): Called Mail() without being connected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18443175/phpmailer-called-mail-without-being-connected)

Can't we use all the configurations for the PHPmailer in an array, Some thing like this:

```
$mail = array(
        'SMTPAuth'  => true,
        'Host'      => 'smtp.millicenthotel.com',
        'Port'      => 25,
        'Username'  => 'info@millicenthotel.com',
        'Password'  => 'gboskeritysoldier1'
        );
```

I tried something like this and it not work. I'm looking for a cleaner way of doing this.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I'm sure you could edit the constructor to accept a configuration/options array.

Comment: @PatrickQ - Indeed you can - but directly configure it using an action hook .see answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you have an action hook called [phpmailer_init](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/phpmailer_init)

from codex :

> The wp_mail function relies on the PHPMailer class to send email
>   through PHP's mail function. The phpmailer_init action hook allows you
>   to hook to the phpmailer object and pass in your own arguments.

example ( [codex again](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/phpmailer_init#Examples) ):

```
add_action( 'phpmailer_init', 'my_phpmailer_example' );

function my_phpmailer_example( $phpmailer ) {
    $phpmailer->IsSMTP();     //switch to smtp
    $phpmailer->Host = 'smtp.example.com';
    $phpmailer->Port = 25;
    $phpmailer->Username = 'yourusername';
    $phpmailer->Password = 'yourpassword';
}
```

Comment: So if it worked for you you might want to [accept](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) the answer by clicking on the small `"V" ` sign under the votes in order to mark the question as answered .